# Regularity of semilinear heat equation

Tags: partial-differential-equations, heat-equation, regularization

I'm facing following regularity issue and i wonder if anyone of you guys is able to help me. I'd like to show that the solution of a semilinear heat equation is classical, i.e. $C^2$ in space and $C^1$ in time:

\begin{align*}
-\partial_t u(x,t) - \Delta u(x,t) +\frac{1}{2} \vert Du(x,t) \vert^2 = f(x,t)) \\
\end{align*}
with the terminal condition $u(x,T) = g(x,T)$, where
$f,g$ are Lipschitz continuous in space, and (1/2)-holdercontinuous in time $(\in C^{0,1/2}(\mathbb{R}^n \times [0,T])$, i.e.
$$\vert f(x_1,t_1) -f(x_2,t_2) \vert \leq C ( \Vert x_1 - x_2\Vert_2 + \vert t_1 - t_2 \vert^{1/2})$$
and uniformly bounded by $C$.

Following statement is found in "linear and quasilinear equations of parabolic type (‎Ladyzhenska):

… under the above assumptions, there is a unique weak holdercontinuous solution $u \in C^{2,1/2}(\mathbb{R}^n \times [0,T])$ (holdercontinuity up to second derivative).

By comparison i was able to show that $\vert Du \vert \leq C$ uniformly in x and t, so that $u$ solves an equation of the form
\begin{align*}
-\partial_t u - \Delta u = A,
\end{align*}
where $A$ is uniformly bounded in $x$ and $t$. In the paper I'm reading the author conclude, that the solution $u$ is classical, but i've got no idea why this is true. I'm not very familiar with the regularity of heat equations and i can't found any hint for the above statement. Is there anyone who is? Thanks a lot!

Comment: [Continuous weak derivatives are classical](http://math.stackexchange.com/q/497708/147263). Does this answer your question?