# Questions about the proof: Continuous function with weak derivatives $\Rightarrow$ $C^1$

Tags: proof-verification, convolution, proof-explanation, regularity-theory-of-pdes, weak-derivatives

For an open set $\Omega$ of class $C^1$, suppose we have $u \in W^{1,p}(\Omega)$  and that $u$ is continuous and all the partial derivatives of $u$ are continuous. I want to show that $u$ is $C^1(\Omega)$ in the classical sense, i.e. that $u$ is continuously differentiable.

I quote here the answer given in the question [Is a continuous function with continuous weak derivatives of class $C^1$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/497708/is-a-continuous-function-with-continuous-weak-derivatives-of-class-c1)?

> Let $\Omega$ be a domain on which $f$ is defined.  Consider  $f_\epsilon = f* \phi_\epsilon$, where $\phi_\epsilon $ is a standard [mollifier](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mollifier). These are defined on a smaller domain $\Omega'\Subset \Omega$. By the basic properties of [convolution](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Convolution),
>
> 1. $f* \phi_\epsilon\to f$ uniformly as $\epsilon \to 0$.
> 2. $\nabla (f*\phi_\epsilon) =   (\nabla f)*\phi_\epsilon$.
> 3. $(\nabla f)*\phi_\epsilon \to \nabla f$ uniformly as $\epsilon \to 0$.
>
> The sequence $f_n=f*\phi_{1/n}$ is Cauchy in the norm of $C^1(\Omega')$. (Indeed, $f_n$ is convergent, hence Cauchy in the uniform norm; the same applies to each partial derivative of $f_n$.)    Since $C^1(\Omega')$ is complete, the sequence converges to an element of $C^1(\Omega')$. This element is $f$, due to item 1.

I have some doubts about the proof, the main one being the following:

Doesn't the convolution need the function $f$ to be defined on all  $\mathbb{R}^n$? But also,

I have only been able to show the result ($f* \phi_\epsilon\to f$ uniformly as $\epsilon \to 0$) for compact (i.e. closed bounded) sets in $\mathbb{R}^n$. Which is the workaround used here?

Comment: There is no workaround: the uniform convergence can be established only on bounded subsets.

Comment: What general domain? I can only see $\Omega'$, which is compactly contained in $\Omega$. The uniform approximation is proved on $\Omega'$, you cannot expect to prove it on $\Omega$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A function is of class $C^1$ on a set if it has a continuous derivative at every point. In other words the property depends only on the local behavior of the function at any point.

Pick a point and then a small ball around it. Now apply your argument to this small ball and deduce that the regularized function converges uniformly on the ball.