# Do continuous weak derivatives imply continuity?

Tags: real-analysis, sobolev-spaces, weak-derivatives

Let $U \subseteq \mathbb{R}^n$ be an open set. Let $f \in W^{1,p}(U)$ and suppose all the weak derivatives of $f$ are continuous. Is $f$ itself continuous?

It is a [classic fact](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/497708/is-a-continuous-function-with-continuous-weak-derivatives-of-class-c1) that *if* we assume a-priori $f$ is also continuous, then it is in $C^1$.

Here, however I do not assume $f$ is continuous.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can show the continuity of $f$ as follows:

If $p = \infty$, then $f$ is Lipschitz continuous and you are done.

In case $p < \infty$, you can consider an open subset $O$ with $\overline O \subset U$. Then, $\overline O$ is compact and the continuous functions $D f$ are bounded on $\overline O$. Now, you can use the Sobolev embedding theorem to get $f \in W^{1,\infty}(O)$. Again, $f$ is Lipschitz on $O$ and (since $O$ was arbitrary), $f$ is continuous on $U$.

Now you know that $f$ is continuous and you can use the technique from the other question to show that $f$ is actually $C^1$.

Comment: Yes, but the fact that if $p=\infty$ then $f$ is Lipschitz isn't quite trivial.

Comment: Thanks. By the way for the case $p < \infty$ Morrey's inequality suffices to show $f$ is continuous. That is you only need to establish $f \in W^{1,p}_{\text{loc}}$ for some $p>n$.

Comment: Hi, I came back to this question now, and I think I am suddenly missing something: When $p>n$ the continuity of $f$ follows from Morrey's inequality. However, I don't understand how do you use Sobolev embedding when $p \le n$? (What version of the theorem are you using?) Thanks.

Comment: You have $f \in W^{1,p}(O)$ and $Df \in L^\infty(O)$. Now, the Sobolev embedding theorem implies $f \in L^q(O)$ for a suitable $q > p$. Together with the regularity of the gradient, you get $f \in W^{1,q}(O)$. Now, you can re-iterate to further increase the regularity of $f$. In fact, you need finitely many applications of the embedding theorem (best think in inverses of the exponents: you start with $1/p$ and each applications decreases this number by $1/n$. After finitely many iterations $k$, $1/p - k/n$ is negative and this means the function is continuous).

Comment: Hmm..., thanks but I think it is a bit more subtle than that. The problem is that you might reach exactly $p=n$, and then you are stuck: it is not clear you are continuous yet, but you cannot proceed another step. Take for example $p= \frac{n}{2}$. Then, after one application of Sobolev's theorem, you get...

Comment: $p^*=n$, so all you have established is $f \in W^{1,n}$, which is not good enough. However, since this question is local, I guess you can always decrease your original exponent $p$ slightly, thus making sure the sequence $1/p - k/n$ ($k=1,2,...$) is never zero. This makes sure you don't "stop accidentally" at the badly-behaved border $p=n$. I think this settles the matter. Thanks again for your time and effort. (I also thought about re-iteration, but somehow I wrongly imagined that you could iterate infinitely many times without surpassing $n$. I now see this is "essentially impossible").

Comment: $p = n$ is not so bad. In fact this implies $f \in W^{1,q}$ for all $q \in (1,\infty)$. Thus you can do a step to a point $q > n$ and then obtain continuity in the next step.

Comment: Can you please elaborate? I think that in general there are non-continuous $W^{1,n}$ functions. I do not see how do you "take the next step" from there (using the bounded derivative assumption of course) except by *lowering* the exponent and then raising it again... (Sobolev inequality is for $p<n$, and Morrey's one is for $p>n$).

Comment: The Sobolev embedding theorem in case $p = n$ implies $f \in L^q(O)$ for all $q \in (1,\infty)$. Together with the gradient, this implies $f \in W^{1,q}(O)$ for all $q \in (1,\infty)$.

Answer (score 3):

It depends on exactly what we mean by "$f$ is continuous". Taken literally, the answer is no: If $$f(x)=\begin{cases}1,&(x=0),
\\0,&(x\ne0)\end{cases}$$then $f$ is not continuous, but the weak derivatives of $f$ equal $0$.

Typically in this sort of context when one says $f$ is continuous one means that $f=g$ almost everywhere, where $g$ is continuous. If that's what we mean then the answer is yes.

**Note**, inspired by a comment: One has to be careful  about jumping to conclusions; the continuity condition above has more or less nothing to do with being continuous almost everywhere! For ease of reference let's label the two:

(i) $f=g$ almost everywhere for some continuous function $g$.

(ii) $f$ is continuous almost everywhere.

On $\Bbb R$, the function $\chi_{(0,\infty)}$ shows that (ii) does not imply (i), while $\chi_{\Bbb Q}$ shows that (i)  does not imply (ii).

**Exercise** investigate the implications, if any, between (i), (ii) and a third version:

(iii) There exists a set $E$ of full measure such that $f_E$ is continuous (wrt to the subspace topology on $E$).

Comment: Yeah, I meant continuous almost everywhere (more formally there exist a continuous representative, which is unique if exists). Regarding your comment above on the case $p=\infty$, you can see my added comment about the case $p < \infty$.

Comment: "more formally"? No, the second condition is not a more formal statement of the first. See edit...