# Smoothness of limit of sequence of functions when sequence of derivatives converges to a continuous function

Tags: real-analysis, derivatives, convergence-divergence, sequence-of-function

This is a follow-up to my [previous question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4250457/smooth-sequence-of-functions-converging-pointwise-to-a-smooth-function-and-limit) on MSE. As in the previous set-up, let $\{ f_n \}$ be a sequence of differentiable real functions over the reals which converges pointwise to some function $f$. We no longer assume that $f$ is smooth. Now let $D: C^\infty (\mathbb{R}) \to C^\infty (\mathbb{R})$ be a smooth differential operator. We had taken $D = \frac{d}{dx}$ earlier.

Assume that $\{ Df_n \}$ converges pointwise to a continuous function $g$, as opposed to being differentiable.

> My new question now is does this imply that $Df$ exists and is continuous?

I am interested in the case of a general $D$ but would be satisfied with $\frac{d}{dx}$, and I would then work to generalize to $D$.

I tried looking up regularity properties of limits of sequences of smooth functions, but nothing came up that seemed relevant. I know that if $Df$ exists and is continuous, then we get that $Df = g$, this is due essentially to the same argument as in the previous question but appropriately generalized. I'm not sure how this would help in solving the problem, though. I've also been thinking about a weak-derivative approach as used in functional analysis but I'm not very knowledgeable in that field.

Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: [This post](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2780348/do-continuous-weak-derivatives-imply-continuity?noredirect=1&lq=1) and [this one](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/497708/is-a-continuous-function-with-continuous-weak-derivatives-of-class-c1?noredirect=1&lq=1) seem very relevant to this problem actually, from the weak derivative point of view.

Answer (score 0):

I've found a counterexample to my question. Let $$f_n(x) = 
     \begin{cases}
       n^2 \frac{x^2}{2} &\quad\text{if } x \in [0, \frac{1}{2n}] \\
       nx-n^2\frac{x^2}{2} -\frac{1}{4} &\quad\text{if } x \in (\frac{1}{2n}, \frac{1}{n}] \\
       \frac{1}{4} &\quad\text{if } x \in (\frac{1}{n},1] 
     \end{cases},
$$

which is in $C^1 (\mathbb{R})$. (I believe this can be bumped to a $C^\infty$ sequence with the use of mollifiers.) We then get

$$f'_n(x) = 
     \begin{cases}
       n^2 x &\quad\text{if } x \in [0, \frac{1}{2n}] \\
       n-n^2x &\quad\text{if } x \in (\frac{1}{2n}, \frac{1}{n}] \\
       0 &\quad\text{if } x \in (\frac{1}{n},1] 
     \end{cases},
$$

which is continuous.

Now $f_n (x)$ converges pointwise to $\frac{1}{4}H(x)$, where $H$ is the Heavyside function, which in particular is NOT continuous (but continuous almost everywhere!), while $f'_n(x)$ converges pointwise to $0$, obviously continuous.

We can't take the derivative of $H(x)$ but <s>we know its weak derivative is $0$</s> (no it's not, see comments). So while this is a counterexample to my question, it (no longer) <s>supports as a valid example of a weaker version of the question:</s>

> Under the original conditions of the question, does $f' = g$ as a weak derivative? And then generalized to $Df = g$ weakly?

Comment: The weak derivative of $H$ is not $0$ but rather a Dirac measure $\delta_0$.

Comment: @YuvalPeres Ah right, missed that. So then I would need to update the conditions of the question to get $f' = g$ weakly. Any suggestions?

Comment: I was about to write a more general counterexample.