# How to show the smoothness of a function in sobolev space by using smoothness of its derivative?

Tags: functional-analysis, sobolev-spaces

$u$ is a function in $W^{1,p}(\Omega)$ for $1\le p \le +\infty$, and its first derivative $\partial u/\partial x^i$ is in $C(\Omega)$( the space of continuous functions on open set(a domain) $\Omega$), then how to show $u$ is in $C^1(\Omega)$?

Comment: Can you find an antiderivative and show that it equals $u$ (except possibly on a set of measure zero)?

Comment: My idea is the same as yours. But the point is how to construct this something anti-derivative.

Comment: This has been answered here before. Take a look [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/497708/is-a-continuous-function-with-continuous-weak-derivatives-of-class-c1), for example.

Comment: Note that in the link @Glitch cited (+1, by the way), the function is assumed continuous. Here, the function $u$ is only assumed to be in $W^{1,p},$ hence only defined up to sets of measure zero, and therefore we can only say that $u$ is equal a.e. to an element of $C^{1}(\Omega)$.