# Partial distributional derivatives are in $L^1_{loc}$ so the distribution is also

Tags: real-analysis, lebesgue-integral, distribution-theory

Let $T$ be a distribution on $\mathbb{R}^{n}$ such that there are functions $f_1,\ldots,f_n \in L^1_{loc}(\mathbb{R}^n)$ so that $\dfrac{\partial T}{\partial x_{j}} = f_j, \forall j=1,...,n. $

My question: How to prove that $T$ is indeed a function in $L^1_{loc}(\mathbb{R}^n)$, i.e. there is $u\in L^1_{loc}(\mathbb{R}^n$) such that
$$T(\phi) = \int_{\mathbb{R}^n}u \phi , \forall \phi\in C_{0}^{\infty}(\mathbb{R}^n)?$$

When $n=1$, a proof can be found [here](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/92311/distributional-derivative-is-locally-integrable-then-the-distribution-as-well). But I could not adapt this since I am not sure how to use the absolute continuity mentioned in [one dimension](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Absolute_continuity) to the case $n>1$.

Comment: Related: https://math.stackexchange.com/q/4817983/168433